# Don't have response result to Server device when distributed load test with jmeter

Tags: jmeter, distributed-testing

I have follow the offical guide of Jmeter about setup distributed load test such as:

- Create rmi key and put it in bin folder of Client device
- Have the same version Jmeter and Java on both of device
- Disable SSL for rmi
- Add remote host in jmeter properties file of Server
- Both device in same subnet.
  When I run the test plan I see that have a delay seem from nearly 1min after I click start, the Client device will show that have been started test plan and the Server will show log that the Remote have started on Client Device, but after the Client Device show that the test plan have been finished the result don't response to the Server Device and it stuck there forever.
  I have trace log of jmeter but it don't have any thing useful, I have tried start the test plan by both way use GUI and CLI but it don't have improve anything.
  I have tried to setup about the port of Client Device is 1234 in server.rmi.localport and run again but it will show the new error "no such object in table"
  Anyone can give me advice how to fix this?

I want it can response the result to the Server device to see the result of test plan

Answer (score 0):

If metrics never come to the master machine it means that the slaves cannot connect back to it to send the results.

The property responsible for the port is `client.rmi.localport` and the default value is `0` which means that the port is allocated randomly.

So if you're going for the default JMeter configuration you need to make to allow all traffic from the slaves machine in the master machine's [firewall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firewall_(computing))

Alternatively you can explicitly set which ports to use for the communication via the aforementioned property, be aware that JMeter opens up to three ports beginning with the port defined in this property

The property needs to be set in the *user.properties* file on each slave machine.

More information:

- [Remote hosts and RMI configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#remote)
- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: Hi thank you for your advice but when do the test plan I have turned off the Firewall but I still have a problem

Comment: Do you have the problem when you run a single JMeter slave and JMeter master on the same machine? If you don't - your RMI configuration is wrong. If you do - your test is not setup correctly. Check [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for the master and the slave for any suspicious entries. It would be a good idea to [increase JMeter logging verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) to DEBUG level.

Comment: Hi, I am not sure about the meaning of running a single JMeter slave and JMeter master on the same machine as you does it mean I will create a VM and test it or just run jmeter test plan on the device?